# Should duplicate flag be in other direction - how to handle?

Tags: discussion, review, duplicate-suggestions

On Workplace.SE (A) [How to deal with an employee who ignores you](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40284/how-to-deal-with-an-employee-who-ignores-you) is marked as a duplicate of (B) [Teammate ignores and excludes me](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17944/teammate-ignores-and-excludes-me) (at the moment I write this, already 4 votes).

(A) is more recent than (B)

But (A) has much higher scores and more/better answers then (B), so I'd rather see (B) being closed as a dupe of (A). (A) can then be refered back to as the best Q/A available.

What to do?

1. Voting to leave open will not have the desired effect because the copycat behavior on duplicate flags will quickly get this question 5 close votes
2. Do nothing, because
   2a. (A) is more recent than (B) and "that's the rule we follow" (assumption)
   2b. questions marked duplicate will remain visible anyway
   2c. other...
3. Flag for moderator attention with the request to reverse the direction.
   I will not do that now because (a mod reading) this meta question will probably trigger such an action if this is the desired one.
4. Other...

[Edit] BTW [Duplicate review should have an option to close the other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150151/duplicate-review-should-have-an-option-to-close-the-other-question?rq=1) is very much related, but the two question compared at that time were about equal in weight

Comment: 4. ask at [meta-tag:per-site-meta] - in case if one can't make a compelling justification to reverse dupe direction within flag message limit (500 chars)

Comment: ..."2a" says "that's the rule" but it ain't so, as explained in [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/165773)

Comment: @gnat. 1) Updated my 2a 2) Yes, that Q says "vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one", but I can only hope others do the same.

Comment: I have just denied the close vote and flagged the other one (the system allows that). Let's see where it goes...

Comment: fate of your flag depends on how clear it is to moderator that newer question is better and how well you presented the case. If it gets declined, you have an option to retry this by opening discussion on Workplace meta